# Cant create new pages - wordpress. Possible Mod-rewrite error?

Tags: wordpress

I've changed my permalink structure to be /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/ through wordpress, however, when I go to create a page it does not seem to work.

My .htaccess looks like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Do I need to add a new "ifModule" in there for pages? If so, please provide one.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your `.htaccess` file and permalink structure won't affect your ability to create new pages, only view existing ones. When you create a new page WordPress uses admin URLs such as `/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page` to show the form and publish changes.

If you try to save a new page, but it isn't listed in the admin console, then new records aren't being created in your database for some reason. It may be that your server has run out of disk space or your account is over disk quota.

If new pages *are* being saved, but *all* pages aren't viewable on your website, then it probably is a permalink problem. The default WordPress `.htaccess` has always worked for me, and the latest 3.2.1 version generates the same rules you've posted. If you're running on a linux web server that should be okay for both posts and pages.

As a last resort you can switch to the default permalink structures such as `/index.php/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/` which doesn't require redirects.

Hope that helps